# Faster way to remove 'extra' spaces (more than 1) from a large range of cells using VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, replace, trim, spaces

How do I remove extra spaces faster, from a large range of cells containing text strings?

Let's say 5000+ cells.

Some ways I have tried include:

```
For Each c In range
    c.Value = Trim(c.Value)
Next c
```

and

```
For Each c In range
    c = WorksheetFunction.Trim(c)
Next c
```

and

```
For Each c In range
    c.Value = Replace(c.Value, "     ", " ")
Next c
```

Any ideas for speed improvement?

Comment: Do you have to use VBA?  You might get performance improvements by operating on the spreadsheet externally using .Net, Python, Perl, etc.

Comment: why dont you use the trim function directly on the spreadsheet? should be significantly faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The loop is killing you.  This will remove spaces in an entire column in one shot:

```
Sub SpaceKiller()
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace _
      What:=" ", _
      Replacement:="", _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      MatchCase:=True
End Sub
```

Adjust the range to suit.  If you want to remove **double** spaces, then:

```
Sub SpaceKiller()
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace _
      What:="  ", _
      Replacement:=" ", _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      MatchCase:=True
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version will replace doubles with singles and then check if there are still still doubles left!

```
Sub SpaceKiller3()
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace _
      What:="  ", _
      Replacement:=" ", _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      MatchCase:=True

   Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Find(What:="  ")
   If r Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "done"
   Else
      MsgBox "please run again"
   End If
End Sub
```

You can re-run until you see ***done***

**EDIT#2:**

based on **Don Donoghue**'s comment, this version will run *recursively* until all double are converted to singles:

```
Sub SpaceKiller3()
   Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Replace _
      What:="  ", _
      Replacement:=" ", _
      SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
      MatchCase:=True

   Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Find(What:="  ")
   If r Is Nothing Then
      MsgBox "done"
   Else
      Call SpaceKiller3
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Gary - this is great except I was hoping for one that removes all the extra spaces and brings it to a single space. 2 to 1, 3 to 1. Like the trim function within excel.

Comment: very nice! could I also use a "do while" to automate?

Comment: Change MsgBox "please run again" to SpaceKiller3 and it will run until there are none.

Comment: @DanDonoghue  **YOU ARE A GENIUS !**  I forgot about doing it recursively!

Comment: It was a quick fix, I would probably go with a Do until r is nothing for a final solution as opposed to self referencing, It's only personal opinion but I am not a fan of subs calling themselves. Great code BTW Gary's Student, I didn't think of using a replace functionality :). Also on a side note, you don't need "Call" there, just the sub name will suffice :).

Answer (score 23):

Late to the party but...

There is no need for iteration through cells/values nor a recursive function to search and replace multiple spaces in a range.

[`Application.Trim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.trim) wil actually take care of multiple spaces between words (and will trim leading/trailing spaces) leaving single spaces in between words intact.

The great thing about it, is that you can feed the function a full range (or array) to do this operation in one sweep!

---

[image]

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A3")
rng.Value = Application.Trim(rng)

End Sub
```

[image]

---

The one thing to take into consideration is that this way you'll overwrite any formulas sitting in your target range with its value. But as per your question, you working with a `Range` object containing text values. There was just no need for iteration =)

Comment: From the VBA Trim() function, I would never guess that the Application.Trim function would work differently. Thank you :)

Comment: :+) for showing a mostly disregarded way @JvdV

Comment: ++ yeah agree with @T.M I rarely see people using this. :)

Comment: I might've encountered a bug with this approach. In one of my worksheets, I  selected multiple cells with Ctrl + Click. Excel wiped out everything and returned #VALUE! All the data are now gone :(

Comment: @HuyTruong. You probably responded to the wrong thread.

Comment: @JvdV. Sorry, I should have explained clearer. I took your solution and tweaked it a little bit. What I wanted was to apply `Application.Trim` to a range of selected cells, which fed into the routine/function via `Application.InputBox`. When the dialog box popped up, I did Ctrl + Click for a few cells, hit OK, and got the return values as #VALUE!

Comment: OP probably should have marked this as answer, depending on whether or not he needed to keep formulas intact.  I had a macro which took 8 minutes to loop through maybe 100k cells and trim them.  Removing the loop and adding `rng.value = Application.Trim(rng)` brought the execution time down to 22 seconds, with only a couple seconds of that being the trim function.

Answer (score 3):

I'm usually using *Evaluate* than loops when it comes on large range. There are so many use of this function, but i won't discuss it further here.

```
'change the row count as deemed necessary..
Set rng = Range("C1:C" & Row.Count)

   rng.value = Evaluate("IF(" & rng.Address & "<>"""", _
               TRIM(" & rng.Address & "),"""")")

Set rng = Nothing
```

Comment: this should be the fastest, but Worksheet.Evaluate is a bit faster than Application.Evaluate `rng = rng.Worksheet.Evaluate("index(trim(" & rng.Address & "),)")`

Comment: Would you mind explaining how does evaluate get to iterate or expand upon the multi-cell range? 

I suppose it would be part of the internal working of "Evaluate". Anyway, your answer was a total life saver (which works as plug and play). You could replace the range with active selection and turn in into a button.

Answer (score 2):

It can depend on many things, but in my case fastest was to get all values at once in array:

```
' Dim range As Range, r As Long, c As Long, a
a = range
For r = 1 To UBound(a)
    For c = 1 To UBound(a, 2)
        a(r, c) = Trim(a(r, c))
    Next
Next
range = a
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a spare column next to it?

```
Range("B1:B" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Formula = "=Trim(A1)"
Columns(2).copy
Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Columns(1).delete
```

Comment: @dan_Donoghue this actually works when needing to remove all spaces after and the extra spaces in between. also very useful. thanks