# How to remove extra spaces from entire excel using VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Set r = Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Find(What:="  ")
     If r Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "done"
```

\
       End If
End Sub

Comment: what code have you already tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768072/fastest-way-to-remove-extra-spaces-more-than-1-from-a-large-range-of-cells-u

These option i tried but not helpful for me..

Comment: Edit your post to include _exactly_ the code you've tried and describe _exactly_ what did and did not work and any error messages you may have received. Otherwise we're just guessing or feeling like a free code-writing service.

Comment: The code you have provided only shows a message when there is no space found. Where is the `Else` part?

Comment: The lack of information makes it hard for us to help you. It also feels like you didn't put much research in your issue before posting the question

Comment: Not any specific code am trying..can any one has any code that they used to remove space so will try to overcome my problem..

Comment: @Antoine.D i did actually but that not helping with my problem so at the end i posted..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below code removes any spaces in the text in col A. Hope this is what you were looking for. Amend the code as necessary.
I have done the changes so that it works for the entire sheet. accept the answer by clicking accept  if it resolves your requirement

```
   Sub teste()

    Dim UsedRng As Range
    Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long, FirstCol As Long, LastCol As Long

    Set UsedRng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    FRow = UsedRng(1).Row
    FCol = UsedRng(1).Column
    lRow = UsedRng(UsedRng.Cells.Count).Row
    Lcol = UsedRng(UsedRng.Cells.Count).Column

For X = FRow To lRow

For Y = FCol To Lcol
        temp = Cells(X, Y).Value
        tempC = (Trim(temp))
        Cells(X, Y).Value = tempC
        Next Y
Next X
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for help. Can we apply the same for entire sheet? (after some modification)