# Excel - VBA : How do I replace the last 3 characters if they are "..."

Tags: excel, vba

Please could you help me a little bit? I am a complete beginner, I don't know anything about programming.

I have the following code that changes double spaces into single spaces and deletes "..." if it's at the beginning of the selected cell(s).

```
Sub Test()
  Dim X As Long, Cell As Range
  For Each Cell In Selection
    For X = Len(Cell.Text) To 1 Step -1
      If Cell.Characters(X - 1, 2).Text = "  " Then Cell.Characters(X, 1).Text = ""
      If Cell.Characters(1, 3).Text = "..." Then Cell.Characters(1, 3).Text = ""
    Next
  Next
End Sub
```

Please could you tell me how I could change the part **If Cell.Characters(1, 3).Text** so that it removes "..." if it's **at the end** of the selected cell(s)?

Comment: I have answerd your question with the assumption you are interested in removing `...` from the *end* of your values. However, above your code you mentioned the beginning of the cells. Can you rectify?

Answer (score 2):

This is not that easy as may seem, since `Excel` has the inclination to adjust three dots into an ellipsis, making it a single character that's unrecognizable when compared to a dot (or three). Furthermore, you don't need to loop characters 1 by 1, instead you could use `Like` to check if a cell is ending with the three dots, or rather the ellipsis. Next to that, we can trim excessive space characters in a `Range` in one go, using `Application.Trim()` as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454080/9758194).

So let's look at example data like:

[image]

Then if we select this `Range` and go over its cells using, for example:

```
Sub Test()

Dim cl As Range
For Each cl In Selection
    If cl.Value Like "*..." Then
        cl.Value = Left(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - 3)
    ElseIf cl.Value Like "*" & ChrW(8230) Then
        cl.Value = Left(cl.Value, Len(cl.Value) - 1)
    End If
Next
Selection.Value = Application.Trim(Selection)

End Sub
```

The results would then be:

[image]

---

And for the sake of fun alternatives, a `RegEx` approach:

```
Sub Test2()

Dim cl As Range
With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    .Global = True
    .Pattern = "…$|\.{3}$"
    For Each cl In Selection
        cl.Value = .Replace(cl.Value, "")
    Next
End With
Selection.Value = Application.Trim(Selection)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification on the three dots.  I was wondering why my answer wasn't working!

Comment: @BrianMStafford Use Insert("")

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works, but it removes all the formatting in the cell, so I cannot use this :(

Comment: That would have been worth mentioning in your question @Dunno123.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you: Use the replace methode to change two spaces into one space. To search for three points at the beginning use the left methode and if it's the case, cut it out with the right methode. Here you have to watch out. Excel often replace three point by the character 133. So you have additional to test for it.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim cell As Range
  For Each cell In Selection

    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "  ", " ")

    If Left(cell.Value, 3) = "..." Then
        cell.Value = Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 3)
    End If

    If Left(cell.Value, 1) = Chr(133) Then
        cell.Value = Right(cell.Value, Len(cell.Value) - 1)
    End If

  Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `Characters(1,3).Insert("")` to change the text

```
Sub Test()
Dim c As Range
Selection.Value = Application.Trim(Selection)
For Each c In Selection
      If c.Characters(1,3).Text = "..." Then c.Characters(1,3).Insert("")
Next
End Sub
```