# Delete the spaces in the middle and end of a certain string from a website

Tags: excel, vba

When I extract a string from a website the textbox shows:

```
<!-- -->  <!--  Principal - CIIU 64207 - TELECOMUNICACIONES -->         <!--    -->     6190 - OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE TELECOMUNICACIONES
```

I use this code to delete the lines and spaces

```
Texto = Trim(Replace(Trim(Replace(Trim(Tabla(24)), "-->", "")), "<!--", ""))
.Txt_Act_Economica.Value = Trim(Texto)
```

The result is:

```
Principal - CIIU 64207 - TELECOMUNICACIONES                     6190 - OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE TELECOMUNICACIONES
```

The Function Trim doesn't delete the spaces in the middle and in the end of the string.

Comment: Trim in VBA only removes spaces at the ends of  string - it will not do anything in the middle of a string.  Also it's possible you don't have actual spaces but "non-breaking spaces" `Chr(160)`   So try `Replace(Tabla(24), Chr(160), " ")` to convert those to regular spaces first.

Comment: Replace(Tabla(24), Chr(160), " ")  doesn't work either =(

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: I expect this "Principal - CIIU 64207 - TELECOMUNICACIONES  6190 - OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE TELECOMUNICACIONES" but now I see that the website shows diferent information like this "<!-- -->  <!--  Principal - CIIU 51906 - VTA. MAY. DE OTROS PRODUCTOS. -->   <!--  Secundaria 1 - CIIU 52593 - OTROS TIPOS DE VENTA POR MENOR. -->      <!--    -->     4690 - VENTA AL POR MAYOR NO ESPECIALIZADA       4799 - OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE VENTA AL POR MENOR NO REALIZADAS EN COMERCIOS, PUESTOS DE VENTA O MERCADOS        4922 - OTRAS ACTIVIDADES DE TRANSPORTE POR VÍA TERRESTRE"

Comment: So as per my previous comment: `Texto = Application.Trim(Replace(Replace(Tabla(24), "-->", ""), "<!--", ""))`

Comment: @Jvdv "Texto = Application.Trim(Replace(Replace(Tabla(24), "-->", ""), "<!--", ""))" doesn't work, by the way, how do you highlight in grey when you answer? `prueba`

Comment: You use backticks around the text you want in grey. Also my suggestion should work fine if there are actual spaces in your text. You might want to find out what those characters really are. Maybe `Application.Clean` would be usefull too.

Comment: =D `Application.Clean` work! Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, the following wouldn't quite get rid of all whitespaces:

```
Texto = Application.Trim(Replace(Replace(Tabla(24), "-->", ""), "<!--", ""))
```

That would indicated other type of whitespace characters, where `Application.Clean` would be usefull:

```
Texto = Application.Clean(Replace(Replace(Tabla(24), "-->", ""), "<!--", ""))
```

Just to be sure of removing spaces you can always nest this into `Application.Trim`:

```
With Application
    Texto = .Trim(.Clean(Replace(Replace(Tabla(24), "-->", ""), "<!--", "")))
End with
```

<sup>**Note:** In contrast to vba's `Trim()`, [`Application.Trim()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454080/9758194) does get rid of unnecessary spaces between word.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I tried the mid() function with find(), see what you think, I have not done this in vba just to show other functions:

[image]

So, in one function:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("Pri",A1,1),FIND("ES",A1,1)-15))
```

Edit, well you could look for the < > combination after, like this:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("Pri",A1,1),FIND(">         <",A1,1)-20)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can't use that function because I extract the data from a website, and anytime I look for information the name of the string "CIIU 64207 - TELECOMUNICACIONES" will change

Comment: @PilarGiannineValeraFernndez see my edit, now looking for the <  > combination after that string - does that change as well?