# Excel Unresponsive after Trim on 6559 Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run this Sub on an excel sheet, single column, 6559 rows of the same 3 repeating 7 digit numbers, using VBA, but it becomes unresponsive. I am not selecting the entire column, only 6559 rows from one column. There are no formulas. Is this normal? What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub TrimWhiteSpace ()
   Dim rng as Range
   Set rng as Selection
   For Each cell In rng
      cell.Value = Trim(cell)
   Next cell
End sub
```

I have tried using trim as both Trim and Trim$.

i7 8cores 32gb ram SSD. Office365 Desktop.

Comment: Probably not related to your issue but you can trim a whole range at once. Possibly faster than looping cells? [https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454080/9758194](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454080/9758194)

Comment: (^^^ note that `Application.Trim` behaves slightly different than `Trim` but definitely suggest you use the former).

Comment: This one would be fast (and if you want to just trim leading/trailing spaces)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46278839/478884

Comment: May be try this:  `cell.Value = Trim(Cstr(cell.Value))`

Comment: Check [this article](https://www.soa.org/news-and-publications/newsletters/compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42/excel-vba-speed-and-efficiency/)

Answer (score 0):

Interacting of macros with sheet cells is time-consuming.
Consider the following code. It takes your Selection to array. Modify it and then paste back. So your macros refers to sheet 2 times only instead of thousands times as in your code.

```
Sub TrimWhiteSpace()
   Dim rng As Range
   Set rng = Selection
   
'   For Each cell In rng
'      cell.Value = Trim(cell)
'   Next cell
    
    Dim rangeArray, i As Long, j As Long
    'Note that if Selection is single cell you'll get an error.
    'Add handling of single cell selection
    
    'put range to array
    rangeArray = rng.Value
    'work with array in memory
    For i = 1 To UBound(rangeArray, 1)
        'If Selection is always one column remove nested j-loop
        'rangeArray(i, 1) = Trim(rangeArray(i, 1))
        For j = 1 To UBound(rangeArray, 2)
            rangeArray(i, j) = Trim(rangeArray(i, j))
        Next
    Next
    'paste back array to range
    rng.Value = rangeArray
End Sub
```

As in @JvdV link this code will replace any formulas by values. But you told your range doesn't contains formulas.