# Add white space before and after (@) ,If @ has adjacent character (before it or after)

Tags: excel, vba

I need to add white space before and after **@** ,If @ has adjacent character (before it or after).
e.g with this strings `new@test` , `new@ test` , `new @test` the expected is **new @ test**.
e.g2  with `@test` the expected is **@ test**
e.g3  with `new@` the expected is **new @**
the below code always replace @ regardless it has adjacent character or not.
thanks for your help.

```
Sub Macro1()
 
    ActiveCell.Replace What:="@", Replacement:=" @ ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Can't you just replace all '@' with ' @ ' and wrap it in `Application.Trim()`, so not the VBA function but the worksheet function. If not, can you show samples where this just wouldn't work? I don't think this is a Regex issue though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve what you want:

```vb
Public Function addSpace(ByVal strText As String, lookFor As String) As String

strText = Replace(Replace(strText, lookFor, " " & lookFor & " "), "  ", " ")
strText = Trim(strText)

addSpace = strText

End Function
```

A test routine would look like:

```vb
Public Sub test()
Dim rg As Range
Set rg = Selection

Dim c As Range
For Each c In rg
    c.Offset(, 1).Value = addSpace(c.Value, "@")
Next

End Sub
```

An example where A1:A5 was selected.

[image]

**Based on @JvdVs comment - an optimized version:**

```vb
Public Function addSpace(ByVal strText As String, lookFor As String) As String

'Using .WorksheetFunction.Trim according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454080/16578424
'@JvdV: https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv
'removes double spaces *within* string as well

With Application.WorksheetFunction
    strText = .Trim(Replace(strText, lookFor, " " & lookFor & " "))
End With

addSpace = strText

End Function
```

Comment: fixed the code according to your requirement

Comment: Now ,It works correctly 

Comment: I added an updated version of the function - based on @JvdV explanation regarding worksheetfunction.trim

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a regex-question. See if you can apply worksheets functions. In the code below I used an implicit range object. Obviously you can adapt the code to be more explicit (or even make it as such that you ask the user for a active selection).

---

Before:

[image]

---

Code:

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range: Set rng = Range("A1:B2")

With Application
    rng = .Trim(.Substitute(rng, "@", " @ "))
End With

End Sub
```

---

After:

[image]

---

**Note**: If your idea is to create a function I wouldn't go to these lenghts and even avoid VBA as native Excel functionality can be used:

```
=TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"@"," @ "))
```

Comment: Btw, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454080/9758194) related post about both pro's and con's of using `Application.Trim()`.

Comment: It works well , I hoped you had first post as an answer.I prefer as function in VBA because the fast iteration on array.