# How to write a regular expression that includes numbers [0-9] and a defined word?

Tags: regex, vba

I'm using VBA and struggling to make a regex.replace function to clean my string cells

Example: "*Foo World 4563*"
What I want: "*World*"

by replacing the **numbers** and the word **"Foo"**

Another example: "*Hello World 435 Foo*", I want "*Hello World*"

This is what my code looks like so far:

```
Public Function Replacement(sInput) As String

Dim regex As New RegExp

With regex
   .Global = True
   .IgnoreCase = True
End With

regex.Pattern = "[0-9,()/-]+\bfoo\b"
Replacement = regex.Replace(sInput, "")

End Function
```

Comment: I'm confused, you wanna replace Foo and 4563?

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```vb
Function Replacement(sInput) As String

Dim regex As New regExp

With regex
   .Global = True
   .IgnoreCase = True
End With

regex.Pattern = "\s*(?:\bfoo\b|\d+)"
Replacement = Trim(regex.Replace(sInput, ""))

End Function
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bM1Dgs/2). Excel test:

[image]

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:\bfoo\b|\d+)` - either a whole word `foo` or one or more digits.

Note the use of `Trim()`, it is necessary to remove leading/trailing spaces that may remain after the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents, capturing preceding whitespace chars when present trying to prevent possible false positives:

```
(^|\s+)(?:foo|\d+)(?=\s+|$)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6VyLTX/1).

---

- `(^|\s+)` - 1st Capture group to assert position is preceded by whitespace or directly at start of string;
- `(?:foo|\d+)` - Non-capture group with the alternation between digits or 'foo';
- `(?=\s+|$)` - Positive lookahead to assert position is followed by whitespace or end-line anchor.

---

```
Sub Test()

Dim arr As Variant: arr = Array("Foo World 4563", "Hello World 435 Foo", "There is a 99% chance of false positives which is foo-bar!")

For Each el In arr
    Debug.Print Replacement(el)
Next

End Sub

Public Function Replacement(sInput) As String

With CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
   .Global = True
   .IgnoreCase = True
   .Pattern = "(^|\s+)(?:foo|\d+)(?=\s+|$)"
   Replacement = Application.Trim(.Replace(sInput, "$1"))
End With

End Function
```

Print:

```
World
Hello World
There is a 99% chance of false positives which is foo-bar!
```

Here [`Application.Trim()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58454080/9758194) does take care of multiple whitespace chars left inside your string.